# request.ValidationErrors() is not a function() express and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a chat application using MEAN stack. where I'm validating registration screen with express-validator package. Below is the source code of package inclusion in my server.js file. where I created a server.

```
let express = require('express');
let application = express();
let path   = require('path');
let db = require("./db");
const server = require('http').createServer(application);
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let expressValidator = require('express-validator')
```

When a user clicks on register button. I will redirect the user to a registation controller where i'm having below piece of code.
 `module.exports.RegisterUser = (req, res) => {
        if (req.body) {
            let user = new userModels(req.body);

```
        req.check('username', 'Not a valid username').isEmail();
        req.check('password', 'password doen\'t meet criteria').isAlpha();

        var validationErrors = req.ValidationErrors();


        if(validationErrors){
            console.log(validationErrors.msg);
        }
        // if there is no validation error
        user.save()
            .then(user => {
                return res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).send("Sign up successfull");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(err);
            });
    } else {
        res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send("Invalid Input");
    }
}`
```

I can able to build the project but wasn't able to validate. I'm getting req.ValidationErrors() is not a function.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt the function `ValidationErrors` starts with a capital letter, seeing as it's not a JSX file.

Comment: oops sorry, I didn't notice that. thanks Sterling Archer

Answer (score 1):

I believe it needs to be:

`const validationErrors = req.validationErrors();`

instead

**EDIT**: Whoops, just noticed Sterling Archer already posted with correct answer. Either way, I'll leave this here as reminder for all of us that don't read well

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

//In function body
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    //Rest logic
}
```